# AJAX code doesn't work in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

JS and HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load_bkissue(accessid){
   //alert(accessid);   
        $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "2.php",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: "accession_id=" + accessid,
    success: function (response) {
        $("#bkid").val(response.accession_id);
        $("#txtbnam").val(response.title);
        $("#txauth").val(response.author);
        $("#txtcat").val(response.category);
        $("#txtsub").val(response.subject_type);
        //$("#txt_div").val(response.rack_no);
        $("#txtrack").val(response.rack_no);
    }
});
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="260" id="tab" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
            <td width="20px"> AccessionNo </td>
            <td width="400px">
                <select name="bkid" onChange="load_bkissue(this.value)" class="txtbox">
            <option value="1">1 </option>
            <option value="2">2 </option>
            <option value="3">3 </option>
            <option value="4">4 </option>
            <option value="5">5 </option>

                        </select>           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Title </td>

            <td><input name="txtbnam" id="txtbnam" type="text"  class="txtbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Author </td>
            <td><input name="txauth" id="txauth" type="text" id="txauth" class="txtbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Category </td>

            <td><input name="txtcat" id="txtcat" type="text" id="txtcat"  class="txtbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Subject </td>
            <td><input name="txtsub" id="txtsub" type="text" id="txtsub"  class="txtbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Rack </td>

            <td><input name="txtrack" id="txtrack" type="text" id="txtrack" class="txtbox"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$json = array(
                'accession_id' => "a",
                'title'        => "b",
                'author'       => "c",
                'category'     => "d",
                'subject_type' => "e",
                'rack_no'      => "f");
echo json_encode($json );
?>
```

When selecting the `AccessionNo`, I need to have these values in each fields like title, author, etc.  But this doesn't work.

Comment: You really need to give more information than "it doesn't work".

Comment: doesn't works, please be a little more descriptive.

Comment: nothing happens..that means values doesn't shows in the textfiels like title,author corresponding to the accessionno

Comment: Did you forget to include jquery in 1.php?

Comment: i included jquery.js in 1.php

Comment: does the alert go off? What happens if you go to 2.php directly?

Comment: you might want to check the javascript debugger in your browser also, to see if there are any exceptions. Maybe there is a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: in the new version, you have extra `')'` characters on nearly every line :-P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON, is...weird. Why not just do it like this:

```
<?php
$json = array(
                'accession_id' => "a",
                'title'        => "b",
                'author'       => "c",
                'category'     => "d",
                'subject_type' => "e",
                'rack_no'      => "f");
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

This results in JSON that looks like this (much more sane):

```
{
    "accession_id":"a",
    "title":"b",
    "author":"c",
    "category":"d",
    "subject_type":"e",
    "rack_no":"f"
}
```

And makes your javascript **much** simpler:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://temp.lmfast1/testajax/2.php",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: "accession_id=" + accessid,
    success: function (response) {
        $("#bkid").val(response.accession_id);
        $("#txtbnam").val(response.title);
        $("#txauth").val(response.author);
        $("#txtcat").val(response.category);
        $("#txtsub").val(response.subject_type);
        //$("#txt_div").val(response.rack_no);
        $("#txtrack").val(response.rack_no);
    }
});
```

Comment: You mean response.title, response.author, etc.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: yea, copy/paste mistake, i'll fix.

Comment: @Ashitha: do you see the alert box you coded? If not, then it isn't even successfully doing the AJAX call...

Comment: I removed the alert box..but no change

Comment: alert doesn't appears now.when executing 2.php it shows an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/temp/workspace/testajax/2.php on line 4

Comment: 2.php shows {"accession_id":"a","title":"b","author":"c","category":"d","subject_type":"e","rack_no":"f"}

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call is missing some important things. Try this call

```
function load_bkissue(accessid) {
    var myID = { accession_id : accessid };
    var DTO = JSON.stringify(myID);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "2.php", // /testajax/2.php
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: DTO,
        success: function(response) //'response' is the output provided by the controller method
        {
            alert(response);
            $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                if (item.field == "accession_id") {
                    $("#bkid").val(item.value);
                } else if (item.field == "title") {
                    $("#txtbnam").val(item.value);
                } else if (item.field == "author") {
                    $("#txauth").val(item.value);
                } else if (item.field == "category") {
                    $("#txtcat").val(item.value);
                } else if (item.field == "subject_type") {
                    $("#txtsub").val(item.value);
                } else if (item.field == "rack_no") {
                    //$("#txt_div").val(item.value);
                    $("#txtrack").val(item.value);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

These are the problems I have seen in your code.

1. No need to give fully qualified URL as your code may not work in different domain ([Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy))
2. You are missing `contentType`
3. You have specified `dataType: 'json'`, but your data is not of type json.